# C/C++: Float Arithmetic Question

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

If a float is repeatedly multiplied by a number that is less than one, is it plausible that the the float could become zero?

Here is an example:

```
float number = 1.0f;

for ( int i = 0; i < ONE_BILLION; ++i )
{
    number *= 0.01f;
}
```

But please don't limit your answer to the example.

Thanks!

Comment: With a simple change to your example code, you could quickly verify this yourself.

Comment: I love symbolic constants like `ONE_BILLION` created for the sole purpose of complying with "no numbers" rules...

Comment: @R.. actually in this case I did `ONE_BILLION` because I didn't want people to have to count the zeros to figure out what the number was.

Comment: Depends on your processor. I think.

Comment: @Jay: You could have written `1000 * 1000 * 1000`.

Comment: @dan04 but why would I want to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, when the result of the multiplication would be smaller than the representable number closest to zero, it will become zero.  With IEEE floating point, this will happen for any multiplier less than or equal to `0.5f` (but greater than zero); however, if the multiplier is even slightly larger than `0.5f` (for instance, `0.5f + FLT_EPSILON`) the result will converge to the smallest representable positive number and stay there forever.  Compare the behavior of this program with and without `-DGREATER`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#ifdef GREATER
#define MULTIPLIER (0.5f + FLT_EPSILON)
#else
#define MULTIPLIER 0.5f
#endif
int
main(void)
{
  float x = 1.0f;
  unsigned int count = 0;
  while (x > 0.0f && count < 200)
  {
    x *= MULTIPLIER;
    printf("%g %a\n", x, x);
    count++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think that when you say "this happens slowest" with 0.5, you mean it doesn't happen in round-to-nearest mode with a factor > 0.5.

Comment: It would happen slowest with 0.9999999999999999 were it not for the possibility of rounding up and not decreasing.

Comment: Indeed, if you change the multiplier to `(0.5f + FLT_EPSILON)` (or, I think, anything in between there and 1), the program goes into an infinite loop at `0x1p-149` (`1.4013e-45`) which I believe is the smallest positive IEEE single-precision denormal.  I will adjust my answer.

Comment: answering the "anything in between" part of your comment, if you get the factor closer to 1 the point at which round-to-nearest prevents you from decreasing further goes higher. With `1.0f - FLT_EPSILON` the fixpoint may be near 0.5 (not tried).

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the implementation. With typical IEEE 754 implementation you'll first get down into denormals (losing precision) and then snap to 0. But some other implementation may give you a floating point underflow error, bang crash.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: No serious platform (not even one lacking denormal support) should crash on underflow in this day and age.

Comment: Not even after calling `fesetenv` with whatever nonstandard arguments are required to enable `SIGFPE` for underflow? `;-)`

Comment: Floating point exceptions don't mean `SIGFPE` is raised. The name `SIGFPE` is a complete misnomer since it can only happen for invalid *integer* operations.

Comment: I'm afraid you're mistaken there.  At least Linux/x86-64 generates SIGFPE if you call `fesetenv(FE_NOMASK_ENV)` and then do anything that would provoke an IEEE floating point exception.  (You have to `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before including any headers or `FE_NOMASK_ENV` will not be available.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Eventually you'll reach a number less than the smallest representable positive float, which will underflow to zero.

Comment: No, there's a whole range of denormal numbers below FLT_MIN in IEEE 754. About 2^23 of them between FLT_MIN and zero.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the multiplied value and on the current rounding mode. Consider this example:

```
FLT_MIN * 0.99 == FLT_MIN
```

**EDIT:** @Pascal: on my computer, this simple example compiled with GCC:

```
int main(){
    float f = 1.0f;
    while (f){
        printf("%g\n", f);
        f *= 0.99f;
    };
    return 0;
}
```

converges to `6.93643e-044`, and not to zero.

My point is that if the intermideate calculations are performed with larger precision than the final result (the most common example is x87 80bit internal FP register), and at the end the result is truncated to `float`, then you'll get a zero for sure. But if the calculations are peformed on float, then you have no garanty at all that they will converge to zero. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa289157) is some good reading.

For general case, the best (and much faster) solution would be to transform the loop to a simple expression with logarithms:

```
#include <math.h>
#define COUNT 1000
#define COEFF 0.9f

int main(){
    float f = 1.0f;
    float f2 = exp(log(f) + COUNT * log(COEFF));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        f *= COEFF;
    printf("results for %d iters with %f: LOOP: %g and LOG: %g\n", COUNT, COEFF, f, f2);
    return 0;
};
```

that will output:

```
results for 1000 iters with 0.900000: LOOP: 5.04467e-045 and LOG: 0
```

Comment: No, this isn't true in IEEE 754 for any rounding mode, and not even for non-standard flush-to-zero. Just try it.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer, but I didn't say that the loop you have written in your extended answer did not converge to a strictly positive value. I said that `FLT_MIN * 0.99 == FLT_MIN` does not hold in IEEE 754 for any rounding mode. Did you try that? `printf("%d\n", FLT_MIN*0.99 == FLT_MIN);` That was my suggestion.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq: no, but  what I wanted to say was that the value to which the loop would converge don't have to be zero, especially for constants that are close to 1.0f.

Comment: And by the way, converging to zero or to a strictly positive number has very little to do with intermediate computations made in higher precision.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that so few pointed out the simple fact that when you go below/above the smallest/largest representable (absolute) non-zero/non-infinite value you will get an underflow/overflow exception which will halt execution. This is because it is mathematically incorrect that a non-zero number (for example) multiplied by a another non-zero number could become zero in the same way that it could become infinity simply by passing a certain point in the scale.

Of course you can mask out the exception(s) in the FP control word and accept that your program behaves mathematically incorrect and eventually deliver a zero which you might plug into a division and get another exception.

In my view it is much better to have control over the FP-processing. I have encountered organizations where they've left integer math for fp to "simplify programming" but have ended up with a processing background which they only vaguely understand and so-called "strange" results and exceptions which they definitely don't.

Comment: Probably because it will not halt execution on any modern system in the default execution mode (all exceptions masked).  A subsequent division by zero wouldn't halt execution either.

Comment: @Stephen Canon: "all exceptions masked" - no wonder so few understand how floating point math works.